# How to handle "Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child"?

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing some server-side rendering with React (with `.renderToString()`). And I noticed that if I send an object instead of a string to React it completely fails, and send this `Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child` error.
Is there a way to catch this error at the component level so that if this happen it doesn't break my entire website?
So far the only option I see is to check the type of everything I'm about to render. But I would like to avoid those systematic changes as it would be very verbose.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options:

1) Use the new [Error Boundaries](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html) to prevent your whole site from crashing. You can wrap a single component in an Error Boundary so that if there is an error in that component, it will show a custom error component and not blow up your entire app.

2) Create a [Higher Order Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) that sanitizes your server data before rendering it. You would wrap any top-level component in the HOC and it could handle converting objects to something that can be rendered or just ignore them altogether.

Comment: Sadly the new Error Boundaries system isn't working for server side rendering :'(